# How PHP form data is submited. (not how to!)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a drag/drop  order list using jquery.Works great.
my question/ issue is with how the data is sent.I am using POST and cannot change that.

How can i keep the same list order to compare against another array?

Example my php code

```
 foreach ($row_array as $row_array) {
echo '<li class="ui-state-default" id="menu_' . $rowid . '"><span class="ui-icon       ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' . $row_array . "</li>\n";
}
```

now as things are dragged and dropped the id's get mixed up. I need the new order to be submitted in some orderly/ predictable fashion.

also,
Is the data sent serial or parallel? That is just for my own curiosity.

thanks for any suggestions.

Here is what is displayed when run.

```
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">

<li id="menu_1" class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li id="menu_2" class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li id="menu_3" class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li id="menu_4" class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li id="menu_5" class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li id="menu_6" class="ui-state-default"></li>
```

and what needs to be submitted via POST preferably in php.

```
<li id="menu_4" class="ui-state-default" style=""></li>
<li id="menu_1" class="ui-state-default" style=""></li>
<li id="menu_2" class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li id="menu_5" class="ui-state-default" style=""></li>
<li id="menu_3" class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li id="menu_6" class="ui-state-default"></li>
```

i am rather new at it but getting comfortable with it.

Comment: You could create a JSON object with your data and then send that data to your server (via POST). it will very likely arrive in the same order.

Comment: "Is the data sent serial or parallel?" Neither, it's all sent as one blob of text/data.

Comment: Not sure if this is just because you've "anonymized" the code, but you are using the same variable for the array and the item in the array here: `foreach ($row_array as $row_array)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use this function http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray

I would do something like this:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({       
   stop: function(event, ui) {              
       var result = $(this).sortable('toArray'); //not sure about "this" here, but probably should work
       $('#some-hidden-element').val(result);
   }
})
```

after each drag that anonymous function will be called and sort will be saved in you hidden element and on form submit correct order will be in that hidden element.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will have to do more research on hidden elements and submitting within a form, in JavaScript. But its the right direction.